# What is the purpose of Table Hints in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the purpose of table hints in SQL Server like `NOLOCK` and `READUNCOMMITTED`?

Please explain this with example.

Also why can't they be specified for tables modified by `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` operations?

Comment: Table hints are used to modify the default behaviour of the query optimizer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

Comment: Regarding your secondary question insert,deletes, and updates **always** take locks irrespective of isolation level so it wouldn't make any sense to allow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They allow you to set transaction isolation level on a table-by-table basis instead of for the entire query or connection.

They can also be used to trigger some features like minimal logging (use `TABLOCK` with the right trace flags set on an `INSERT` and it can be minimally logged).

As a rule it's a better idea to use connection-level settings.

Answer (score 1):

As the commentor pointed out, Books Online has an excellent description (and samples) of Table Hints, including which hints can be used for which operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx

There is also a big fat caveat at the top of the page, which often goes unnoticed:

> Caution  Because the SQL Server query optimizer typically selects the
>   best execution plan for a query, we recommend that hints be used only
>   as a last resort by experienced developers and database
>   administrators.

While the accuracy of the optimizer in choosing the best plan can be debatable, the latter half of the warning is certainly true; don't use Table Hints unless you are sure that you need them, and that assurance typically only comes with experience.